# Align audio track to reference audio

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm editing a music video with one camera but multiple microphones. It's a rather cheap setup, so I had everyone record audio on their phones individually and I plan on using the audio from the camera as a "master" that I can align everything else to.

In other software such as Kdenlive and DaVinci Resolve, there's a button in the context menu that will synchronize playback between audio tracks. The audio tracks would be perfectly in sync and I could remove the audio from the video since it was terrible.

Is there a way to do this in Blender's VSE? I need to use Blender for certain graphics, but if I have to, I could just do it in Kdenlive and then finalize the graphics in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning the tracks in something precise like Audacity, REAPER or Adobe Audition (to name a couple examples), render it as a lossless file even if the original format is lossy so you're not losing more information, then drag those into Blender. Smartphone microphones can have frequency responses that are unoptimised for music so there may be additional mixing to do outside of Blender.

It's worth mentioning that, although you wanted to do this in Blender, it is not ideal for editing audio and it is best to establish a workflow that involves multiple programs where Blender is not suited.